# how to show the list for any type to print in console after run like deriving show?

Tags: haskell

1. how to show the list for any type to print in console after run
2. how to enumerate the list to check all the types in the list whether the same?
3. Is there a kind of dynamic type like .net framework? is there the most upper root superior type in Haskell to represent all types?

#### code

```
mhead :: [a] -> [a]
mhead (x:xs) = [head (x:xs)]

main :: IO ()
main =  do
  let b = [1,2,3,4,5]
  let aaa = mhead [1,2,3,4,5]
  putStrLn aaa;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble making any sense of your question. It might be better split up into separate questions, but you also need to clearly explain what you are specifically stuck on and how the code you post relates to your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance.

Comment: @Khovanov, it is strange, because he also put your question on hold as 'unclear what you're asking'. So he understands your question and deems it unclear at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your questions:

1. Have a look at the [Data.Typable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.0.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) lib. (?)
2. Types in a list are always the same - if you have a list of type `::[a]` every item of it has the type `a` (for excample `[Int]`, `[String]`, ...)
3. Wow there is indeed a lib for this too [Data.Dynamic](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Dynamic.html) - never had guessed

For your code I can see no question so I don't really know how to answer any.
But you should get this type-error:

```
No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘1’
In the expression: 1
In the first argument of ‘mhead’, namely ‘[1, 2, 3, 4, ....]’
In the expression: mhead [1, 2, 3, 4, ....]
```

This is because you try to print the result with `putStrLn` and this wants its input to be of type `String` (which is `[Char]`). 
So Haskell tries to make `1` into a `Char`(which could work if `Char` would be an instance of `Num` which of course it's not).

You can *repair* this if you use `print` instead:

```
main :: IO ()
main =  do
  let b = [1,2,3,4,5]
  let aaa = mhead [1,2,3,4,5]
  print aaa
```

But for this kinds of *experiments* I would suggest using GHCi anyway - you can have a much faster feedpack this way (so instead of wriring a full programm just load your file into GCHi  and try out the stuff like `let aaa = mhead [1,2,3,4,5]` there directly)

Comment: I'd like to add that Data.Typeable and Data.Dynamic are _not_ for beginners, and it's better to get used to the functional programming way of doing things rather than trying to replicate the way you programmed in another type of language.